# Persisting ServerSyncProvider on server in WCF Service Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, persistence, microsoft-sync-framework

I am building an occasionally connected system using Microsoft Synchronization Framework with WCF as the transport medium.  The client application builds a SyncAgent with a SqlCe synchronization provider as the local provider, and a ServerSyncProviderProxy as the remote provider.

In the service implementation running on the server, I have the following instance properties:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MMFSyncService : IMMFSyncService
{
    private const string cstrDatabaseProvider = "DatabaseProvider";
    private const string cstrFileProvider = "FileProvider";

    private MobileApplications _application;
    private MMFDatabaseSynchronizationScopes _scope;

    private Dictionary<string, IMMFServerSyncProvider> _syncProviders;

    ...
}
```

The `_syncProviders` collection needs to be able to persist from call to call so that multiple synchronizations are possible and it doesn't need to be reinitialized each time.  When I was building the application and running it through the Visual Studio built in "web server" this code worked perfectly, however, having deployed to a remote IIS server now, the `_syncProviders` object is null on subsequent service calls.

From what I have read, this is expected behavior with WCF, and it was only an oddity of running it in shared memory in Visual Studio that ever allowed this to work.  There appears to be two approaches to fixing this issue though, either using a "DurableService" to persist data to a database between calls or setting the ServiceBehavior to a context mode of Single and for per performant applications the DurableService solution is the only approach to consider.

It seems like for WCF implementations of Synchronization Framework, this is a necessity, but I haven't seen it discussed in any blogs/articles.  Am I missing something in my deployment process?  Are there other solutions to this problem that I should consider?